# can you use plinqo with T4 or other code generation tools???

Tags: codesmith, plinqo

I want to use plinqo for my personal project, but seem like you need codesmith pro.  its 299 bucks.

is there a way we can use it with other code generation tools?  I only need it for linq many to many.

Answer (score 1):

PLINQO is a set of CodeSmith Generator templates and thus requires CodeSmith Generator to be used. You could always use the [trial](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/generator) and see how you like it before purchasing it.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski

Comment: @BlakeNeimyjski is there anything in the license for the CodeSmith.Data or Templates that requires a copy of CodeSmithGenerator to be purchased?

Comment: @JJS No, you don't need a license of Generator, but you won't be able to run the templates without Generator.

Comment: @BlackNeimyjski the templates are intimately bound to SchemaExplorer. I think most people miss the value proposition of the Generator product as 'only' the generation engine. Total Value = engine + schemaexplorer + templates. Much like the legs of a stool. When you pull one out, the stool collapses.

Comment: Yes, the templates require a licensed copy Generator to Generate, but the generated code doesn't have any dependencies on Generator.